# How can you have one Hudson job with multiple levels of users run with different options?

Tags: hudson, jobs

I am working with Hudson here and I am trying to create a single job that users with different access can run.  Based on their access level, they would see different options.

For instance:

A Developer when running this job would see the build stage and be able to see the build process, and deploy it to a development server.

The Release Engineer would see the same options as the developer, but also see that he can deploy the code to a different set of servers as well.

And so forth.

Is this even possible, like role based jobs.  I know I can limit the access and who can do what, but this is a little different.